# Spanning a matrix in LaTeX over two pages

Tags: latex, matrix, html

I have a matrix with more than 80 rows. How can I tell latex that I want it to continue over to the next page rather than stop showing the remaining after it has reached the end of the page?

Perhaps I should add that the matrix is of the following nature:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\[
\bordermatrix{
~ & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \cr
    1 & 0.0741 & 0.0741 & 0 & 0 & 0.0741 & 0.7778    \cr
    2 &  0.2097 & 0.0806 & 0.0081 & 0.0323 & 0.0403 & 0.629  \cr
```

etc...

Thanks
andreas

Comment: This would be a good question on [The TeX SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).  Quickly, though, while you can stretch the array across two pages I'm not sure about the delimiters.  You might try putting the matrix in a separate document, compiling it to PDF, then including it with different windows on two pages.  But do you really need to put this matrix in a paper?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `longtable` package. Here is [the manual](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable).

Answer (score 0):

Try `\usepackage{longtable}` then replace `\begin{tabular}` with `\begin{longtable}`.

Comment: But how would I add parenthesis?